# Which is the best way to create an empty set in builder object

Tags: java, collections, immutable-collections, immutables-library

A class has a Set of String objects defined as its instance variable.

Step-1: I have a method which creates an object for this class, assign an empty set of String to the instance variable and then returns the object.

The method which receives it, passes it to another method which adds more String to that empty set.

Now how should I create the empty set in Step-1?

a. Using `Collections.<String>emptyList()` creates an immutable Set of strings and this isn't giving an error when new Strings are added later in the second method. Needed some details on the fundamentals on how this is happening.

b. `new HashSet<>()` This creates a mutable map.

Which is the right approach and why? Is there another good way?

Comment: `emptyList()` does not create a `Set`…

Answer (score 4):

It sounds from your question as if you are producing an instance via a builder, and then later somebody tries to modify the produced instance.

Don't write it like that; builders should virtually always return immutables. If during the build process no elements are added to the set, then `Set.of()` it is (or, in pre-JDK9 API, `Collections.emptySet()`). These will throw when you try to add to them, which is the point.

If your intent is to create a mutable object, via builder or no, obviously some mutable set is required then. Possibly HashSet, but note that HashSet is normally a bad idea with builders; the general expectation is that order is maintained, so you'd need `LinkedHashSet` instead, or, preferably, something like guava's `ImmutableSet` which is more optimized.

Comment: You said an exception will be thrown. Will that be a runtime exception because compilation is happening fine using a immutables  set. How is this happening?

Will try to refactor in order to make the build instance remains unchanged.

Comment: The type 'Set' has an add method. It just does, java does not let you monkey around with types. The implementation returned by e.g. Collections.emptySet has implemented this add method using the following one-liner: `throw new UnsupportedOperationException();`.

Comment: Now it makes sense as the UnsupportedOperationException is runtime exception.